# It is unable to display selected value from drop down menu

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have an application you can view here to test [APPLICATION,](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text16.php) but I am having to little issues I can't seem to figure out.

1. Even though the queries are correct it is not able to display the module selected in code below:

   ```
      <p>
       <strong>Selected Module:</strong><?php $dbModuleNo;?> - <?php$dbModuleName;?> <input type='hidden' value='<?php$_POST["module"];?>'>
       </p>
   ```
2. How can I display `Please Select Module` and `Please Select an Assessment` messages only after the user has selected a `Please Select` option from one of the relevant drop down menus and submitting it:

Code is below (I commented out queries):

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
                <?php            
                /*
                $moduleactive = 1;
                $sql = "SELECT ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName FROM Module WHERE ModuleActive = ? ORDER BY ModuleNo"; 

                $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);
                $sqlstmt->bind_param("i", $moduleactive);
                $sqlstmt->execute(); 
                $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbModuleId,$dbModuleNo,$dbModuleName);
                $sqlstmt->store_result();
                $sqlnum = $sqlstmt->num_rows();
                */
                ?>
                Module: 
                <select name="module" id="modulesDrop">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    <?php
                    while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
                        $ov = $dbModuleNo . "_" . $dbModuleName . "_" . $dbModuleId; 
                        if($ov == $_POST["module"]) 
                            echo "<option selected='true' value='$ov'>$dbModuleNo - $dbModuleName</option>" . PHP_EOL; 
                        else 
                            echo "<option value='$ov'>$dbModuleNo - $dbModuleName</option>" . PHP_EOL;
                     } 
                    ?>
                </select>
                <input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" />
            </form>
    <?php if(isset($_POST["module"]) && $_POST["module"] != "") { ?>
            <form action="" method="post"> 
                <p>
                <strong>Selected Module:</strong><?php $dbModuleNo;?> - <?php$dbModuleName;?> <input type='hidden' value='<?php$_POST["module"];?>'>
                </p>
                Asessments: 
                <?php
                /*
                $sessionquery = "
                    SELECT s.SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId, SessionActive, Complete
                    FROM Session s
                    INNER JOIN Session_Complete sc ON sc.SessionId = s.SessionId
                    WHERE
                    (ModuleId = ? AND SessionActive = ? AND Complete = ?)
                    ORDER BY SessionName 
                    ";
                $active = 1;
                $complete = 1;
                $sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
                // You only need to call bind_param once
                $sessionqrystmt->bind_param("iii",$moduleId, $active, $complete);
                // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
                $sessionqrystmt->execute(); 
                $sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionName,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId, $dbSessionActive, $dbComplete);
                $sessionqrystmt->store_result();
                $sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();        
                */

            if ($sessionnum == 0 ){    ?>
                <span class='red'>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</span>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    <?php
                        while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
                            $sv = $dbSessionId;
                            if($sv == $_POST["session"]) 
                                echo "<option selected='true' value='$sv'>$dbSessionName - date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dbSessionDate)) - date('H:i',strtotime($dbSessionTime))</option>" . PHP_EOL;
                            else
                                echo "<option value='$sv'>$dbSessionName - date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dbSessionDate)) - date('H:i',strtotime($dbSessionTime))</option>" . PHP_EOL;
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Assigments">
            </form>
            <br>
            <br>
            <?php
    if(isset($_POST["session"]) && $_POST["session"] != "")    {

    /*
            $sessiondetailsquery = "
                SELECT s.SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, SessionDuration, SessionWeight, TotalMarks, 
                s.ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName, s.Room, Building, Capacity, SessionActive, Complete, PenaltyEnabled, COUNT(PenaltyMarks)
                FROM Module m
                INNER JOIN Session s ON m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId
                INNER JOIN Session_Complete sc ON sc.SessionId = s.SessionId
                LEFT JOIN Room r ON s.Room = r.Room
                LEFT JOIN Penalty p ON s.SessionId = p.SessionId
                LEFT JOIN Penalty_Marks pm ON s.SessionId = pm.SessionId
                WHERE
                (s.SessionId = ?)";
            $active = 1;
            $complete = 1;
            $sessiondetailsqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessiondetailsquery);
            // You only need to call bind_param once
            $sessiondetailsqrystmt->bind_param("i",$dbSessionId);
            // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
            $sessiondetailsqrystmt->execute(); 
            $sessiondetailsqrystmt->bind_result($detailsSessionId,$detailsSessionName,$detailsSessionDate,$detailsSessionTime, $detailsSessionDuration, $detailsSessionWeight, 
            $detailsTotalMarks, $detailsModuleId, $detailsModuleNo, $detailsModuleName, $detailsRoom, $detailsBuilding, $dbCapacity, $detailsSessionActive, $detailsComplete, 
            $dbPenaltyEnabled, $dbCountPenalyMarks);?>
            */
            <h3>CHOSEN ASSESSMENT</h3>
            <input type='text' id='currentId' name='Idcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='$detailsSessionId' /></td> 
            <br>
            <strong>Assessment:</strong> <?php $detailsSessionName; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
            <p><strong class='red'>Please Select an Assessment</strong></p>
    <?php } } } else { ?>
            <p><strong class='red'>Please Select a Module</strong></p>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: you're not `echo`ing... try `<?php echo $dbModuleNo;?>`

Comment: selected='true'  should be selected='selected'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<strong>Selected Module:</strong> - <?php$dbModuleName;?> <input type='hidden' value='<?php$_POST["module"];?>'>
```

This is your error. If you view source you ll see that PHP code is being printed as it is because you are not spacing it properly. Try this

```
<strong>Selected Module:</strong> - <?php echo $dbModuleName;?> <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $_POST["module"];?>'>
```

`<?php$dbModuleName;?>`  should be `<?php echo $dbModuleName;?>`